# Updating or removing non-pointer elements from Array in Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

We are running some code on Parse.com (yep, still, the migration is slow, and that shouldn't be the issue), and we are trying to setup a competition list for our highscores, basically creating some short-term lists of scores.

I want to update an element in an array, to change some values. The elements are JSON objects like this:

```
{
    "firstPlay":"2016-06-06T12:51:30.009Z",
    "lastPlay":"2016-06-   06T13:52:17.864Z",
    "name":"NAME","plays":19,
    "score":897817,
    "user":   {"objectId":"7jGpJE7KZ5"}
}
```

The first solution we did was to fetch the list of objects, change the element for the current user, and then save the object containing the list. Obviously, this has lead to some loss of data, even in small scale tests. I figured we needed to use .add and .remove to fix this. I would love it if there was a way to simply update an element in a list, but I haven't found it.

Anyway, the code we're running looks like this:

```
var list = results[contest].get("list");
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    newEntry = list[i];
    console.log("found user!" + request.user.id);
    foundUser = true;
    if(newEntry.score < request.params.score){
        newEntry.score = request.params.score;
    }
    newEntry.plays++;
    newEntry.lastPlay = new Date(Date.now());

    results[contest].remove("list",list[i]);
    results[contest].save().then(function(removed){
        console.log("contest is saved!");
        results[contest].add("list",newEntry);
        results[contest].save();
    }); 
}
```

The console prints "contest is saved!" as expected, but the old entry is not removed - I get new entries added, which floods my list.

I figure this has something to do with the way Parse checks for objects equality in lists, and the examples I've found have all used arrays of Parse objects, which I'm not using. Does anyone know a way to update the elements of a list, without the risk of losing data?

The solution we're looking at currently is to change the structure to reference a different class of Parse objects, instead of JSONS, but I just don't see why we can't use .remove() like I'm trying to!